# For positive real numbers $a,b$ prove that $\sqrt[3]{2(a+b)(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b})}\ge\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{a}}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, means, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> For positive real numbers $a,b$ prove that $$\sqrt[3]{2(a+b)(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b})}\ge\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{a}}$$

Here's what I've gotten to so far,
$2(a+b)(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b})$
$=2(1+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}+1)$
$=2(2+\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab})$
$=2(\frac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{ab})$
$=2(\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab})$
I'm not sure where to go from here, I'm pretty sure I have to use the $A.M-G.M$ inequality in some way, but I'm not sure how it'd be used as both sides of the inequality look like $G.M$ inequalities. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1946919p13423425, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2537138p21600129.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you mind sharing how you found the problem on AoPS? I wasn't able to find it when I searched before posting my question.

Comment: I don't know if that works but maybe Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @Cookie: [With Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B2(a%2Bb)(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bb%7D)%7D%5Cge%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B%5Cfrac%7Bb%7D%7Ba%7D%7D%24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $x=\sqrt[3]{a/b}$, then you have to prove $$4+2x^3+{2\over x^3}\geq (x+{1\over x})^3$$

> Notice that if $t>0$ then  $$t^3-3t+2 = (t+2)(t-1)^2\geq 0 $$

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Aqua answer, with $x = \sqrt[3]{b\over a}\;$, but then let
$y=\left(x+{1\over x}\right)$

$y^3 = \left(x+{1\over x}\right)^3 = \left(x^3+{1\over x^3}\right) + 3y\;$

We have to proof:

$\begin{align}
4 + 2·(y^3 - 3y) &≥ y^3\\
y^3 - 6y + 4 &≥ 0
\end{align}$

AM-GM inequality: $\;y = \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right) ≥ 2×\sqrt{x×\frac{1}{x}} = 2\;$
Let $z=y-2$

$(z+2)^3 - 6(z+2) + 4 = (z^3+6z^2+12z+8) - 6z - 8 = z^3+6z^2+6z ≥ 0$

With positive coefficients, and $z≥0$, above is always true. **QED**